# How do I prevent Pyro4 from closing the connection after COMMTIMEOUT

Tags: python, asynccallback, pyro

I have the following situation; My Pyro4 project has a server and a client. The server contains a method which need to call 2 callbacks on the same callback object. So class `Callback` has two callback methods: `Callback()` and `SecondCallback()`. There is some delay between the calls of those callback methods. I've simulated this delay in my example by calling `time.sleep`.

I need to set a timeout on Pyro4 (`Pyro4.config.COMMTIMEOUT`), because without one, the Pyro4 daemon will never break out of the `requestLoop` method. This works perfectly when calling just one callback method, but when you have to call a second callback method, the Pyro4 callback daemon closes the connection after the first callback method was called + the timeout.

I've tried to set the timeout to a bigger amount, but this timeout is also the time the `requestLoop` method blocks untill it processes the loopCondition.

An example script which demonstrates my issue is included below. You need to start it by starting a server after you started the Pyro4 nameserver:

`python -m Pyro4.naming`

`python test.py -s`

And afterwards starting a client in a new cmd window:

`python test.py`

`Test.py`

```
import Pyro4, time
from argparse import ArgumentParser

ip = "127.0.0.1"

class Server:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def ActionOne(self):
        return "Foo"

    def ActionTwo(self):
        return "Bar"

    @Pyro4.oneway
    def ActionThree(self, callback):
        time.sleep(4)
        callback.Callback()
        time.sleep(3)
        callback.SecondCallback()

class Callback:

    def __init__(self):
        self.Executed = False
        pass

    def Callback(self):
        print "FooBar"

    def SecondCallback(self):
        print "raBooF"
        self.Executed = True

def loopWhile(condition):
    while condition:
        time.sleep(.1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--server", "-s", action="store_true")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    if(args.server):
        print "Server"

        daemon = Pyro4.core.Daemon(host=ip)
        uri = daemon.register(Server())

        ns = Pyro4.naming.locateNS(host=ip)
        ns.register("server", uri)

        daemon.requestLoop()

        pass
    else:
        print "Client"
        Pyro4.config.COMMTIMEOUT = .5

        ns = Pyro4.naming.locateNS(host=ip)
        serverUri = ns.lookup("server")
        proxy = Pyro4.core.Proxy(serverUri)

        print proxy.ActionOne()
        print proxy.ActionTwo()

        daemon = Pyro4.core.Daemon(host=ip)
        callback = Callback()
        daemon.register(callback)

        proxy.ActionThree(callback)
        daemon.requestLoop(lambda: not callback.Executed)
        print "FINISHED"
```

The result of this script:

`Server`:

```
Server
Exception in thread Thread-17:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\threading.py", line 552, in _T
hread__bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\threading.py", line 505, in ru
n
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 22, in ActionThree
    callback.SecondCallback()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\Pyro4\core.py",
line 171, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\Pyro4\core.py",
line 410, in _pyroInvoke
    msg = message.Message.recv(self._pyroConnection, [message.MSG_RESULT], hmac_
key=self._pyroHmacKey)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\Pyro4\message.py
", line 168, in recv
    msg = cls.from_header(connection.recv(cls.header_size))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\Pyro4\socketutil
.py", line 448, in recv
    return receiveData(self.sock, size)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\Pyro4\socketutil
.py", line 190, in receiveData
    raise ConnectionClosedError("receiving: connection lost: " + str(x))
ConnectionClosedError: receiving: connection lost: [Errno 10022] A request to se
nd or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when
sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

`Client`:

```
Client
Foo
Bar
FooBar
```

My final question is: How do I prevent Pyro4 from closing the connection after COMMTIMEOUT expired when a second callback is called?

I hope all this information is clear enough to understand.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference:

I was able to restart the connection to the callback by calling:

`callback._pyroReconnect()`

Just before calling the second callback method

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit strange, to be honest.

On the one hand you're configuring COMMTIMEOUT to a (very low) value of 0.5 seconds, thereby enabling the concept of timeouts. On the other hand you're asking to not get a timeout that closes the connection on the server.  What is it you want?

But yeah, you can use `_pyroReconnect` to reconnect a proxy that has been disconnected. Also see the readmes and code of the `autoreconnect` and `disconnects` examples that come with Pyro4.

Comment: This time-out is on the client side and means that it will wait 500ms for response. In my case I am using callbacks, which acts as a server, therefore I find it a bit strange that the connection to the callback gets closed, but the connection with the proxy on the server not.

Comment: Your client code transfers full control to the daemon.requestLoop method and as such doesn't do anything anymore with the client proxy. So there's nothing to register any timeout to.